# How to invoke the my C# exe file when html submit button pressed?

Tags: html, c#-4.0

I have my Application(.exe) written in C#. Now I want to invoke my exe (C# application) when my html form submit button pressed.

Is this possible to solve my problem?

Comment: No, you can't start applications on a user's machine when they click a button on a webpage. And even if you *could*, you shouldn't. Remind me never to visit a webpage you've created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this on a public webpage, it would be a bad security hole if it were possible. You can redirect a user to a file, which may open their default application for it (like what happens when you click on .pdf link for instance) though.

If this is for a local application, HTA files might be an option too - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113678/How-to-execute-a-Local-File-using-HTML-Application.aspx?msg=3639837